# Test a variable against a set of values

Tags: perl

In perl, what's the best way of testing a variable against multiple values?

Something like this (in pseudo code):

```
if x is in {'q','w','e','r','t'}
  # do something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
if (grep /^x$/, ('q', 'w','e','r','t')) {
  # Do something
}
```

This works if the values you are comparing are scalars (strings or numbers).

For strings, there is a nice shorthand:

```
if (grep /^x$/, qw(q w e r t y)) {
  # Do something
}
```

If you don't like the regex notation (`/^x$/`), there is:

grep {$_ eq 'x'} qw(q w e r t y)

Where you can use `$_` to test for anything, not just equality.

If what you want to do is simple (can be expressed in a line), just this will do:

```
do_something if grep /^x$/, qw(q w e r t y)
```

Comment: just x is my variable, so probably $x

Comment: OMG I wish I had a teacher like you. That's easy to understand and superb.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the ["new"](http://p3rl.org/perl5100delta) [smart match operator](http://p3rl.org/perlop#Smartmatch-Operator) could be used for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

my $thing   = 'bar';
my @set     = qw(foo bar baz);

say 'ok!' if $thing ~~ @set;
```

Output:

```
ok!
```

**Note**: this isn't available in ancient versions of perl. Before 5.10, you want to use [`grep`](http://p3rl.org/grep) as in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13719709/1184510), or, if your set is very big, [`first` of List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util) because it wouldn't iterate over the whole list after the first match.

Comment: Sets can also be modelled with hashes: `my @vals = qw(foo bar baz); my %set = map {$_=>1} @vals;` then `$set{$thing}` is true when the thing is inside the set. Works only for strings, but is an *O(1)* operation. Very good on big data sets with frequent (n > 1) access.

Comment: @amon Yeah, great. :) However, I used the name *set* just because in the problem element ordering probably doesn't matter and because the OP asked about something like an `a in B` operation.

Comment: +1 Wow. Thanks for this, it's nice to see how Perl5 has evolved. Last I used Perl in any big project was when it was still 5.8.x - I still love Perl but it's mainly a `sed`/`awk` replacement to me these days.

Comment: **beware:** smartmatch was always experimental, and is now slated to be deprecated and removed; see: https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2022/12/msg265180.html